# Elasticsearch as a service for GCP

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

As far as I'm aware, there are no managed elasticsearch solutions **provided by** Google Cloud Platform, such as there is [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) on AWS.

I've opened a feature request ticket for this on the issue-tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121304973), but I was wondering if there is a service somewhere on GCP that I'm missing? If not, are there plans to build an ES service on top of GCP? And if so, is there a general timeline on when that will be GA?

Comment: Absolute bummer GCP doesn't have one yet.

Answer (score 4):

When configuring your cluster on [ES Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud) (the cloud operated by Elastic Inc), you have the choice between hosting it on [AWS or on GCP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-configure-deployment-settings.html#ec-platform). If you pick GCP, the cluster is fully managed by Elastic on GCP.

This is a commercial feature (but [AWS Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) is too), but you have a 14 days free trial to see how it looks like.

Also worth reading:

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/hosted-elasticsearch-services-roundup-elastic-cloud-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service
- https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service

Comment: yes, we currently use that, but I'd like this to be managed within/by GCP.

Comment: @David542 is this what you're looking for? https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-and-google-team-up-to-bring-a-more-native-elasticsearch-service-experience-on-google-cloud

Comment: nice!! Finally, something a bit more integrated.

Comment: Is this a billing integration like AWS Marketplace (which lacks all the instance sizes due to the number of SKUs) OR will this be more than that? I have seen limitations with the Elastic Cloud custom scheduling (of "Allocators") and no iops QOS.... would be nice to see it managed by k8s operators and native security (I.e no logging into the Elastic Cloud UI)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for creating a feature request!

Regarding Elasticsearch on GCP, I am not 100% sure if it will apply for your case but there is a solution on **Google Marketplace**. It is [Elasticsearch Service on Elastic Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/elastic-saas/elastic-cloud) offered by Google on GCP. Check it out and see if you can use it.

Comment: That's basically the same service I'm mentioning in my answer ;-)

Comment: @Andrei Cusnir -- right, I know. I'm saying are there any plans to have an **actual** GCP service for it. As in, like CloudSQL.